# Vanilla JS category selector .removeAttribute problem

Tags: javascript, html, filter, attributes, selection

New on dev and JS following a (apparently) simple tutorial I got stacked in a silly problem, a function that has to select categories just adding or removing attributes.
It adds (and hides) but doesn't remove (and lets appear).

Function:

```
var showAndHideSongs = function(event, filter) {
    // get all songs that match the genre of the filter
    var songsByGenre = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('#playlist [data-genre="' + filter + '"]')
    );

    // if checkbox is checked, show songs
    // otherwise, hide them

    if (event.target.cheched) {
      songsByGenre.forEach(function(song) {
      song.removeAttribute("hidden");

      });
    } else {
      songsByGenre.forEach(function(song) {
        song.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
      });
    }
  };
```

HTML:

```
<ol id="playlist">
      <li data-genre="pop">
        "Thank U, Next" by Arianna Grande
      </li>
      <li....
```

Checkboxes are dynamically created:

```
 var renderCheckLists = function(genres) {
        app.innerHTML =
          "<h2>Filter Songs</h2><h3>By Genre</h3>" +
          genres
            .map(function(genre) {
              var html =
                "<label>" +
                '<input type="checkbox" checked data-filter="' +
                genre +
                '" checked>' +
                genre +
                "</label>";

              return html;
            })
```

I tried literally everything but the solution
As I said it removes but looks like if "removeAttibute" doesn't work.

I tried the removeAttribute in a blank test project and actually works perfectly, so the problem is not there

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what is `event.target.cheched`? I do not see any checkbox.

Comment: thanks
Checkboxes are dynamically created 

 var renderCheckLists = function(genres) {
        app.innerHTML =
          "<h2>Filter Songs</h2><h3>By Genre</h3>" +
          genres
            .map(function(genre) {
              var html =
                "<label>" +
                '<input type="checkbox" checked data-filter="' +
                genre +
                '" checked>' +
                genre +
                "</label>";

              return html;
            })

Comment: There is spelling mistake - `event.target.cheched` should be `event.target.checked`

Comment: yes!!!!

Thanks a lott!!